# Creating a more compact layout in GraphViz using dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a directed graph on 31 nodes for which Graphviz' dot layout engine produces the following layout:

[image]

I'm unhappy with the layout because there is too much space surrounding the four-node-cluster 8-10-20-21. What settings can I tweak to improve Graphviz' layout of graphs like these? Interestingly, if I change the direction of the 25-21 edge I get a much more compact layout:

[image]

I guess this is because Graphviz strongly believes that all edges should point downwards. Perhaps I tell Graphviz that it is ok for some edges to point upwards?

You can play with the graph [here](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%22%22%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%20%5Bbgcolor%3Dtransparent%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dpi%3D150%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontname%3DInconsolata%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rankdir%3DTB%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ranksep%3D0.3%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20splines%3Dtrue%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bfillcolor%3Dwhite%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3Dbox%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3D0.55%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edge%20%5Barrowsize%3D0.7%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontsize%3D%2210pt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

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the offending edge as `"21" -> "25" [dir = "back"];` to keep the original arrow while changing the sense of the hierarchy implicit in the dot layout.

using `constraint = false` can help in some circumstances, but it often results in the layout of the edge to be routed in an unexpected (read ugly) path.

Comment: Is this a new feature in Graphviz? Because when I try it it changes the direction of the edge which I don't want.

Comment: The feature is long standing. You should add the `dir=back` attribute after changing the direction of the edge (21 to 25 in your case). Swapping the nodes give the layout you desire, and the attribute leaves the arrow pointing in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **dot** definitely `strongly believes that all edges should point downwards`!  While you can indicate that specific edges can skip that rule (reversing edge direction, `rank=same`, and `constraint=false`), I can't think of any way to generally relax the rule. (for details, see https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html).
But if a hierarcical view is not important, try some of the other engines (**neato**, **fdp**, **circo**, **twopi**).  This is an "eye-of-the-beholder" thing, but I liked `neato -Nlen=1.8 -Gmode=hier -Goverlap=false`
Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. But it seem to cause too many edge overlaps and reorders the vertices too much.